Type Compatibility Error When Passing Subclass to PHP Interface Method
Why do I get a type compatibility error in PHP when I try to pass an object of class RegisterRequest, which inherits from BaseRequest, to an interface method that expects an object of type BaseRequest.
interface RequestDecoderInterface
{
    public function decode(BaseRequest $request): AbstractParams;
}

class RegisterRequestDecoder implements RequestDecoderInterface
{
    public function decode(RegisterRequest $request): RegisterParams
    {
        return new RegisterParams(
            $request->email,
            $request->firstName,
            $request->lastName,
            $request->password,
            $request->secondName,
            $request->address,
            $request->phoneNumber,
            $request->gender,
            new \DateTime($request->birthday),
            $request->avatar
        );
    }
}

class RegisterRequest extends BaseRequest
{
...

Error: Declaration must be compatible with RequestDecoderInterface->decode(request: \App\Shared\BaseRequest)
